# Appropriate layers of design abstraction for objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I've been getting back into ASP MVC development recently, and with EF 6 I had a few questions about the design logic.

I'm going with the following pattern:
Controller -> Service -> Repository -> DbContext -> Database

I read some stuff about the UnitOfWork pattern, but I always make something similar to this:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : IDisposable
{
    SiteContext Context;
    public BaseRepository(SiteContext context) { 
        Context = context; 
        IsContextDisposable = false; 
    }

    public BaseRepository() { 
        Context = new SiteContext(); 
        IsContextDisposable = true; 
    }
}

public class ForumRepository : BaseRepository
{
}
```

So if some method requires multiple repos, it can just pass around its a single DbContext and dispose of it later.

**Questions**:

1. Should my repository be working with the Entity Framework Models (that are used to construct my code-first database)? Or should the repo fetch them and immediately convert the EF models into domain objects using Automapper or something similar?
2. What is the point of the service? Why can't I just instantiate a repository directly from the controller? What is the responsibility of the Service?
3. Is it a normal flow to have Entity Models converted to Domain Objects then converted into ViewModels?

Comment: *DbContext in an async manner since then, the upper level might think the Repo is finished with it and prematurely dispose of it* - to my knowledge this can't happen.

Comment: yeah, I'm going to edit my post since I've been doing a lot of reading about how DbContext is not thread-safe, and that it's apparently not a huge deal to spin up another context.

Comment: Async and threading are not the same thing AT ALL.

Comment: sorry I wasn't referring to the C# async pattern, I was referring to multithreading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to question 2 is loose coupling. If you use the repository directly in your controller that creates a tight coupling and if you ever want to change your data access, you will have to change the controllers. If you have the service layer, you won't be required to change the controllers. Now if your repository is based on an interface (let's call it IDAL) that defines all the data access methods you might want (e.g. GetBooksByAuthor etc), you can do away with the service layer and inject the respository directly into your controller. This way if you ever want to change the dataaccess, you can derive from the IDAL interface and inject this new concrete data access layer into your controller.

The answers to 1 and 3 depends on the complexity of your application. If your database tables closely match your domain objects then the repo can directly work the entity models. If not, then it's best to convert them into domain objects and pass them on to service or controller for further business logic. Domain models would normally be converted into ViewModel in controller before sending it to view.

Comment: Hey Harsh, thanks for the insight. OOC, in your experience, which do you prefer, going through a service layer, or some kind of IRepository interface with dependency injection?

Comment: I personally like the IRepository Interface with DI better. There are a couple of advantages for this: 1. It makes testing easier. In your unit test, you can create a mock implementation of IRepository and pass it to the controller. 2. If you want to support multiple databases or if you want to change the database,  you can simply create another implementation of IRepo and inject the implementation you want as and when required. With the service layer approach, the controller always calls the service which directly calls the repository there is still some (indirect) coupling.

Comment: oh okay, does that mean you put your business logic in the controllers then? Shouldn't the business logic be separate from the presentation layer?